# Signatures on a document

Tags: nouns

Please help me use the correct term to indicate: "Please [sign with a shorthand version of your signature] all these pages and then sign in full on the last page."

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a shorthand version of your signature", but in general, when a full signature is not required, but some sort of proof is required that something has been read, I see "Please initial...", e.g., "Please initial each change, and sign the bottom of the final page.".

Comment: Thank you, @JeffZeitlin. Yes, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is something like:

*Please initial each page and sign your name on the last page.*

The verb, "[to initial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/initial)," means (1) to affix an initial to, and (2) to authenticate or give preliminary approval to by affixing the initials of an authorizing representative.